Update code to Joomla 4 which validates login from a mobile app
I am trying to update this code from joomla 3 to joomla 4 which validates login information stored in the joomla database from a mobile app. The information is passed by json from the mobile app to joomla. The code is in a subfolder outside of the traditional structure of joomla 4 which may be an issue also, but worked in joomla 3. I do believe I have defined the application correctly.
My knowledge is limited on joomla 4 so any help would be helpful. I have included the changes that I have tried to implement so far without any success.
<?php

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication;
use Joomla\Session\SessionInterface;
use Joomla\Session\Session;
use Joomla\Session\Handler\DatabaseHandler;
use Joomla\DI\Container;
use Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver;


use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\Pluginhelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Authentication\Authentication; 

use Joomla\CMS\User\UserHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\User\User;


define('_JEXEC', 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    

  define('JPATH_BASE', str_replace("/webservices","",dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
    $class_name             =  new \Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication;
    $session_alias          = 'session.web';
    $session_suffix         = 'web.site';
    
 
// Boot the DI container
$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();

// Alias the session service key to the web session service.
$container->alias($session_alias, 'session.' . $session_suffix)
            ->alias('JSession', 'session.' . $session_suffix)
            ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Session\Session::class, 'session.' . $session_suffix)
            ->alias(\Joomla\Session\Session::class, 'session.' . $session_suffix)
            ->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.' . $session_suffix);

// Instantiate the application.
$app = $container->get($class_name::class);
// Set the application as global app
 \Joomla\CMS\Factory::$application = $app;
 
 

$input_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if (!$input_data) {
$input_data = new stdClass(); }


if ($input_data->controller == "login") {
    $data = array();
    $data['username'] = $input_data->username;
    $username = $input_data->username;
    $data['password'] = $input_data->password;
    $options = array();
    $options['remember'] = false;
    $options['return'] = "";

    // Get the database connection using Joomla 4 Factory
    $db = Factory::getDbo();

    // Prepare the query to check user and group information
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select($db->quoteName(['group_id', 'user_id']))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__users', 'G'))
        ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__user_usergroup_map', 'O') . ' ON ' . $db->quoteName('G.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('O.user_id'))
        ->where($db->quoteName('G.username') . ' = ' . $db->quote($username));

    // Set and execute the query
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    if (count($results) > 0) {
        foreach ($results as $value) {
            // Check if the user is in a valid group (31 or 46)
            if ($value->group_id == 31 || $value->group_id == 46) {
                // Prepare the login credentials
                $credentials = array();
                $credentials['username'] = $data['username'];
                $credentials['password'] = $data['password'];
                $credentials['secretkey'] = "";  // Only needed if using two-factor authentication
                $options['skip_joomdlehooks'] = true; // Skip hooks if needed

                // Attempt to log in
                if (true !== $app->login($credentials, $options)) {
                    // Login failed
                    $result = json_encode(array("status" => 0, "message" => "Not logged in, username or password is wrong."));
                } else {
                    // Login successful, retrieve session ID
                    $session = Factory::getSession();
                    $result = json_encode(array(
                        "status" => 1,
                        "session_id" => $session->getId(),
                        "group_id" => $value->group_id,
                        "user_id" => $value->user_id,
                        "message" => "logged in"
                    ));
                }
                break;
            } else {
                // User is not in a valid group
                $result = json_encode(array("status" => 0, "message" => "This account does not belong to a valid user group."));
            }
        }
    } else {
        // No user found or invalid username/password
        $result = json_encode(array("status" => 0, "message" => "Invalid username or password."));
    }

    // Output the result as JSON
    
    print_r($result);
   
}

